# Scraping the data from Google Maps

Tags: python-2.7

The problem is to collect the map coordinates of some given locations and display on the site that i'm creating.I have heard that it is called Scraping.Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, google does not allow scraping from their services. You can use the api for this though. https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 0):

Google has really tight controls on what they let you get to -- there's [an API](https://developers.google.com/maps/), but there are limits on the order of [1,000 queries/day](https://developers.google.com/places/usage), depending on what information you need exactly. If you try to get around their API, they have incredibly clever algorithms that shut you out immediately -- attempting to scrape Google search results, I found that after a few minutes, they were able to immediately block me as soon as I hopped on new Tor endpoints.

The people at Google are extremely good software developers, and if they don't want you to have some info, you can't get it.

Comment: I disagree your quote "The people at Google are extremely good software developers", may be  i am not correct, because there are many softwares in  market that scrape google maps data efficiently.